# Ajuda com uma view MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Estou lendo o [esse](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mvvm/mvvm_first_application.htm) tutorial sobre MVVM. Porém estou sem entender o seguinte:

```
<Window x:Class = "MVVMDemo.MainWindow"
   xmlns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   xmlns:d = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
   xmlns:mc = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
   xmlns:local = "clr-namespace:MVVMDemo"
   xmlns:views = "clr-namespace:MVVMDemo.Views"
   mc:Ignorable = "d"
   Title = "MainWindow" Height = "350" Width = "525">

   <Grid>
      <views:StudentView x:Name = "StudentViewControl" Loaded = "StudentViewControl_Loaded"/>
   </Grid>

</Window>
```

---

```
using System.Windows;

namespace MVVMDemo {

   /// <summary>
      /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
   /// </summary>

   public partial class MainWindow : Window {

      public MainWindow() {
         InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void StudentViewControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
         MVVMDemo.ViewModel.StudentViewModel studentViewModelObject = 
            new MVVMDemo.ViewModel.StudentViewModel();
         studentViewModelObject.LoadStudents();

         StudentViewControl.DataContext = studentViewModelObject;
      }
   }
}
```

Pergunta:

Em que momento e onde foi criada a classe `StudentViewControl` a qual tem a propriedade `DataContext` alterada na ultima linha do método `StudentViewControl_Loaded` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você olhar no projeto usado pelo tutorial, verá que há uma `ViewModel` com o nome de `StudentViewModel` e um `UserControl` que é a `View` com o nome de *StudentView*. *StudentViewControl* é só o `name` que ele atribuiu para a `view`que ele está usando... No tutorial é o **Step 6**

Comment: Um, seria então como uma variável. Algo como `studentViewControl = new StudentView()`. Seria isso?
Causou certa confusão por ele ter usado CamelCase, dai para mim deu a impressão de que se tratava de uma nova classe.

Comment: Ele cria essa "instância"  do *StudentViewControl* quando usa `<views:StudentView x:Name = "StudentViewControl" Loaded = "StudentViewControl_Loaded"/>` a partir daí ele pode acessar `StudentViewControl.DataContext`